# Should states in an FSM be friends with the context type?

Tags: c++, friend, state-machine, pushdown-automaton

I've built a class-based Push-down Automaton Finite State Machine. The context class (the class whose internal state is being modified) has some methods that only the states should access (incrementing/decrementing some iterators, pushing/popping states, setting an accepting state, etc). Right now they are public due to the different states needing access to them.

Would it be better to make the methods protected/private and define the states as friends of the context?

(nb4 "opinion-based!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be reasonable to make a collection of classes that work together for a common purpose friends, but there is one alternative you might consider.

For a really short, naive example:

```
class outer
{
 private:

 int a;
 int b;

 public:
 class inner
    { public:
      outer * o;

      inner( outer * io ) : o( io ) { o->a = 0; }

    };

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
 outer o;
 outer::inner i( &o );

 return 0;
}
```

I did this quickly, so the construction of inner taking a pointer isn't really good C++, so don't take THAT as advice.

The point is that this compiles even though inner is accessing private members of outer.

That's another way of doing what you've asked.

Comment: This solution does not scale very well. Increasing the number of inner classes by a factor of 10 makes it unwieldy and hard to read. :(